# using template class using directive into another template

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I've the following template, which scope is only to create some `using` declarations that I need elsewhere:

```cpp
template<
  typename VariableType,
  size_t StateSize,
  template<size_t, typename> typename IntegrationStrategy
>
class Configuration {
public:

  using State = std::array<VariableType, StateSize>;
  using Strategy = IntegrationStrategy<StateSize, VariableType>;
  using Var = VariableType;
};
```

It seems to work, because this code compiles:

```cpp
template <size_t StateSize, typename VariableType>
class RungeKutta4 {

};

// ...
using Conf = Configuration<double, 5, RungeKutta4>;


static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, Conf::Var>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::array<double, 5>, Conf::State>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<RungeKutta4<5, double>, Conf::Strategy>);
```

Now I want to use the `Configuration` as template argument in another class, because I need to use `Var`, `State`, and `Strategy` that it defines:

```cpp
template <Configuration Conf>
class DifferentialEquation {
public:

  void dummy(const Conf::State& state) {}
};
```

Unfortunately this code does not compile. I've also tried something like template template parameters:

```cpp
template <template<
  typename,
  size_t,
  template<size_t, typename> typename> typename Conf>
class DifferentialEquation {
public:

  void dummy(const Conf::State& state) {}
};
```

But it does not work.

What should I use as template argument in my `DifferentialEquation` class in order to use the `using` declaration inside my `Configuration` specialization, and use `Conf::State` in methods and parameters inside that class?

EDIT:

This is the error when I try to compile the last `DifferentialEquation`:

```
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C3205: argument list for template template parameter 'Conf' is missing
  /DifferentialEquation.hpp(40): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'DifferentialEquation<Conf>' being compiled
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C2144: syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by ')'
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C2144: syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by ';'
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C2039: 'State': is not a member of '`global namespace''
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '&'
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
\DifferentialEquation.hpp(22): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

EDIT:

I'm trying to follow suggestion in order to add template arguments to `Conf`, but I'm not able to add the third argument, the template one.

If I add names to template arguments it compiles:

```cpp
template <template<
  typename X,
  size_t Y,
  template<size_t, typename> typename Z> typename Conf>
class DifferentialEquation {
public:

  // void dummy(const Conf::State& state) {}
};
```

But when I try to use it does not compile:

```cpp
template <template<
  typename X,
  size_t Y,
  template<size_t, typename> typename Z> typename Conf>
class DifferentialEquation {
public:

  void dummy(const Conf::State<X, Y, Z>& state) {} // error
  void dummy(const Conf<X, Y, Z<Y, X>>::State& state) {} // error
};
```

What's the right combination that I should use?

Comment: The common way of doing this is to add the template parameters needed for `Conf` to the top most template parameter list as shown in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358178/12002570).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I use as template argument in my DifferentialEquation class in order to use the using declaration inside my Configuration specialization, and use Conf::State in methods and parameters inside that class?

The common way(**syntax-wise**) of doing this is by adding the template parameters needed for the `Conf` to the top most template parameter list as shown below:

```
template <template<
  typename,
  size_t,
  template<size_t, typename> typename> typename Conf,
  //note these next three parameter are added so that we can used them as arguments of Conf
  typename T, 
  std::size_t t,
  template<size_t, typename>typename temp>
class DifferentialEquation {
public:

  void dummy(const typename Conf<T, t, temp>::State& state) {} //works now 
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WKqo1Kejs)

---

Also, wherever needed(if any) do add the `typename` or `template` keyword in the above code.

Comment: It works on Clang and GCC but unfortunately I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and I've a compilation error: error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'State'  https://godbolt.org/z/f3KnqE6vr

Comment: @Jepessen Just add the keyword `typename` as done in this [modified demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WKqo1Kejs) and it works in msvc also. I have updated the code in my answer to reflect the same. Now the code works in all compilers. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rxKbc7zYr). That is why I had a note at the end of my answer.

Comment: I can create an instance of `DifferentialEquation` with `DifferentialEquation<Configuration, double, 3, RungeKutta> diffEq;`. Is there a way to use  `using Conf = Configuration<double, 3, RungeKutta>; DifferentialEquation<Conf> diffEq;` since it was my original purpose?

Comment: @Jepessen Feel free to ask a new separate question for the follow up questions as there is a word limit in the comment section and also the comments get deleted very often. I would also recommend that in your new question, you can remove the unnecessary code and include in that only the code that shows your new question(which is how to create an instance like `DifferentialEquation<Conf> diffEq;` instead of `DifferentialEquation<Configuration, double, 3, RungeKutta> diffEq;`).

Comment: @Jepessen Note that `Conf` is a "type" whereas `Configuration` is a template name, so what `DifferentialEquation<Conf> diffEq;` doesn't make sense because as I already said `Conf` is a type and not a template name.